# Issue with Load XML

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an xml file which has data like:

```
<root>
<application>
    <field name="ApplicationName">Google App</field>
    <Group>
    <field name="GroupName">MidasGoogleAppsUsers</field>

    <field name="UserName">knikkhoo</field>
    <field name="UserName">devendrat</field>
    </Group>    

</application>

</root>
```

Then I tried LOAD XML function to insert data of this XML into the database:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'UserApplication.xml'
INTO TABLE userapplication
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<application>';
```

But after insertion I get only 1 single row with data as:

```
ID  ApplicationName GroupName   UserName
1   Google App  MidasGoogleAppsUsers    devendrat
```

The output I desire is:

```
ID  ApplicationName GroupName   UserName
1   Google App  MidasGoogleAppsUsers    devendrat
2   Google App  MidasGoogleAppsUsers    knikkhoo
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Can you simplified the XML structure:

```
<list>
  <detail>
      <ApplicationName>Google App</ApplicationName>
      <GroupName>MidasGoogleAppsUsers</GroupName>
      <UserName>devendrat</UserName>
  </detail>
  <detail>
      <ApplicationName>Google App</ApplicationName>
      <GroupName>MidasGoogleAppsUsers</GroupName>
      <UserName>knikkhoo</UserName>
  </detail>
</list>
```

Use below code to import it:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'sample.xml' INTO TABLE details  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<detail>';
```

Hope this will help !!

~K

Comment: I have tried this and this works but if simplified the XML strucutre in this manner than XML data will to long

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if you change  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY `<application>` to `<Group>`

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'UserApplication.xml'
INTO TABLE userapplication
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Group>';
```

Comment: Then also I got the same output as was getting before.. A single row only.. I think some changes need to be done in XML format.